# How to access nested objects from get request

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, pug

I have a form that is sending and saving JSON to MongoDB via mongoose perfectly.

However, when I try to access this data the nested objects render to the get route html page as:

```
{ synth: { patch_name: 'dd', synths: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] }, _id: 534e438e585246b81eaef158, __v: 0 }        
{ synth: { patch_name: 'dd', synths: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] }, _id: 534e438f3f356cb01b6b4f9c, __v: 0 }        
{ synth: { patch_name: 'dd', synths: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] }, _id: 534e43b17d4e9eb0153cd69b, __v: 0 }
```

If you notice all the nested objects simply say 'object'.

I'm confused as to how to access this information

**Here is my get request**

```
app.get('/returnedData', function(req, res){
  Synth.find({}, function (err, docs) {
    res.render('returnedData', {
      title: 'Tasks index view',
      docs: docs    
    });
  });
});
```

**Here's my little jade loop**

```
  each synth in docs
            tr
              td #{synth}
```

I tried a bunch of shot-in-the-dark 'solutions for this and none worked.

Here's one of them

```
docs: docs.synth
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Node's `util.inspect` might help: http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options

`util.inspect(synth, {depth: null})` should result in printing the entire object, no matter how deep (giving `depth` a null value means "keep going until you hit the bottom"). You could either process the array and hand that off to Jade, or pass the function into the template to call on each `synth`.